# iPhone peer-to-peer voice chat

Tags: iphone, flash, voip, sip, gamekit

I see that Game Kit allows you to develop games with [voice chat](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/AddingVoiceChat/AddingVoiceChat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH103-SW1).
I want to build a more general, peer-to-peer voice chat application, that does not have to live in the Game Center. So a couple questions:
1. What peer to peer system/technologies could be used for this? 
2. If I wanted to allow voice chat with a Flash client (i.e. iPhone app <--> Server <---> Flash client on PC) would options for 1 work for this?

I have some experience with RTFMP for Flash to Flash client chat, and no iPhone dev experience, so just want to test out some ideas.

Maybe one idea: build using the Ribbit Platform - they have both Objective-C and Flash SDKs, but this looks more like traditional\SIP calling.

Anyway, would appreciate anything that points me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now that flash has access to raw Microphone data, you could roll your own client and server; yet, since, currently, it doesn't have UDP sockets in AIR for mobile, you would be forced into considering audio quality vs lagg with even tighter restrictions then usual.

You can now roll your own native extension to make this work; yet, I am assuming you want something that only requires coding in AS3.

Therefore, considering your restrictions, the only real bet would be to use Flash's built-in communications capabilities (e.g. RTMP).

With the above being said, there are opensource alternatives to the array of Adobe's own flash communication servers:

[the red5 server](http://www.red5.org/), and [rtmpd](http://www.rtmpd.com/).

IMHO Ribbit's services are kind of pointless.